# mechanicalsoup doesn't find an existing tag

Tags: python-3.x, mechanicalsoup

My problem: Till 03/31/2018  my function get_settldays() returned the expected  datevalues. Since then settlDays.contents is empty;
but checking this tag in the Mozilla browser, there is the expected content

```
import sys, mechanicalsoup, re, datetime
def get_settldays(soup):
    settlDays = soup.find('select', id="cmeTradeDate")
    settlDays = re.findall('\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d',str(settlDays.contents))
    return [datetime.datetime.strptime(adat, '%m/%d/%Y') for adat in settlDays]

url =  "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html"
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
try:
    browser.open(url)
except:
    print('Error:',  str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
    browser.close()
    quit()
soup = browser.get_current_page()

settlDays = soup.find('select', id="cmeTradeDate")
print('\nsettlDays', settlDays)  #remains empty??
print('\nsettlDays.content', settlDays.contents)
browser.session.close()
browser.close()
```

Is there an idea why settlDays.contents remains empty??

Answer (score 0):

The content of `<select id="cmeTradeDate">...</select>` is populated with javascript. Without javascript, the contents are just `\n` instead of a list of date options. You can verify this in a browser like Chrome by going into Settings -> Content settings -> JavaScript and toggling "Allowed" to the off position and then reloading the page.

Since MechanicalSoup does not support javascript, you might want to consider a tool like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead.